# Spring Security Redirecting to invalid-session-url on a fresh application launch

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have just configured session management into my web app, but Spring keeps redirecting to the invalid-session-url specified in the session management. When the contextPath is been launched in the browser before me attempting login and session expiring.

This is my configuration below:

```
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/styles/calvary.css" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/styles/vendor/foundation.min.css" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/styles/vendor/normalize.css" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/styles/fonts/gothic.eot" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/styles/fonts/gothic.woff" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/styles/fonts/gothic.ttf" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/vendor/vendor/modernizr.js" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/vendor/vendor/jquery.js" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/vendor/foundation/foundation.min.js" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/vendor/foundation/foundation.abide.js" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/calvary.js" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/images/lg.png" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/images/red_indicator.gif" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
            <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index"  authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
            <logout  logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="false" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
            <csrf/>
            <session-management  session-authentication-error-url="/login?expire=3" invalid-session-url="/login?expire=3" session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
                <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?expire"/>
            </session-management>
            
    </http>
    
    
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="calvaryLogger"/>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean name="calvaryLogger" class="com.apr.authenticator.CalvaryLogger" /> 
</beans:beans>
```

I will really appreciate any assistance.
Thanks

**EDIT**

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
        <error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/WEB-INF/viewList/404.html</location>
      </error-page>
   </web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please post the Error Stack Trace for above sceneio ?

Comment: there is no any error stack trace

Comment: So, which invalid url it is driving u 2 ?

Comment: invalid-session-url="/login?expire=3" Meanwhile this is at a new lauch attempt before user even attempts to login at all.

Comment: Have u configure Spring Security Filter ?

Comment: Please find my web.xml above

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked quite some time ago, but this happened to me recently.

Once the user logs out and logs back in, Spring security seems to see my session as invalid and always directs me to whatever `invalid-session-url` is set to.

what I just did was remove this setting from my xml and the issue went away.

So instead of:

```
<session-management  session-authentication-error-url="/login?expire=3" invalid-session-url="/login?expire=3" session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?expire"/>
</session-management>
```

Try:

```
<session-management  session-authentication-error-url="/login?expire=3" session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?expire"/>
</session-management>
```

Comment: It seems there's no way out of it! I had to remove the `invalidSessionUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems ! There is an error while creating the session. Please map your configuration with the [Spring-Security](http://www.journaldev.com/2736/spring-mvc-security-example-using-in-memory-userdetailsservice-and-jdbc-authentication) App.